# Decidability of regularity of context-free grammar

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar, decidability

I've searched for a long time, but cannot find this. Maybe it's an open problem, but it seems not *that* hard.

Let's say I have a context-free grammar, say in Chomsky normal form for definiteness. Is there an algorithm to check whether it generates a regular language?

Of course, some simple cases can be easily decided, but I want to know whether there is a general procedure. I also know that for general grammars it is undecidable. If it is an open problem, so be it, but I won't think it is just because I haven't been able to find the answer. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following theorems are proved in Jeffrey Shallit's *A Second Course in Formal Languages and Automata Theory*.

**Theorem 6.6.6.** It is undecidable whether, given a CFG $G$, $L(G)$ is regular.

**Theorem 6.6.7.** There exists no algorithm that, given a CFG $G$ such that $L(G)$ is regular, outputs a DFA that accepts $L(G)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Not only for answering my question (and the one I intended to ask afterwards, too:), but for opening to me a whole new world of "Sequel to Formal Languages". :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabio for the reference. So regularity of languages given by contex-free grammars is not decidable. Is it known that it is not even recursively enumerable?